# Is SetInterval() to milliseconds too much for browser?

Tags: javascript, error-handling, setinterval

I have made a JavaScript Stopwatch that works by incementing the value of a variable every second (using `setInterval(stopwatchValue, 1000)`). I have some issues though: if the user hits pause at, say, 3.8 seconds, the actual pause value will be 3 seconds (when they click resume, the stop watch will continue from 3.0 seconds instead of 3.8).

I DO have a solution to fix this. My idea is too update the stopwatch every split second by doing something like `setInterval(stopwatchValue, 1)`.

My question is: Is it too much for the browser to handle this code every split second:

```
function stopwatchValue("result") {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = timer;
    timer++; 
}
```

ALSO: Some people have said you should avoid accessing the DOM more than once if you can. In my case, would it work if I replaced my above code with:

```
var displayResultHere = document.getElementById("result");
function stopwatchValue("result") {
    displayResultHere = timer;
    timer++; 
}
```

My Stopwatch: hntr.atwebpages.com/stopwatch/stopwatch.html

Comment: Can't rely on setInterval at all for precision timers. Make sure you store start time and compare to that each instance

Comment: @charlietfl ahh yes. you reminded me off my OTHER question: if the browser was suffering some kind of performace issues, would that slow down the setInterval()?

Comment: Yes it definitely will and that's why you can't rely on it alone. Also using `1ms` probably won't work as browser has a minimum which i think is about `4ms` and may vary between browsers

Comment: @charlietfl So the best bet would be to save the system time when user clicks start and compare that each time?

Comment: `if the user hits pause` does the event that this emits have a timestamp property, perhaps?

Comment: I was about to say something about the 4ms thing. You can read more detail about that here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Minimum_delay_and_timeout_nesting

Comment: by the way, for the display side of things, I'd use `requestAnimationFrame` - though, without seeing an at least partly working version of your code, it's hard to say if that would be appropriate

Comment: @Jaromanda X I added a link to the stopwatch, which you cn have a look at the source code if you wish.

Comment: [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jaromanda/wy2j5pmq/) uses `requestAnimationFrame` as I suggested earlier - with minimal changes to your code - I see someone posted an answer since with requestAnimationFrame, however, I don't think their code would behave the same as yours

Comment: note, that code attaches event listeners to buttons - though, that was when I was using the timestamp of the click event - which is no longer used , so that's a little redundant :p

Comment: What does "too much" mean? Please close or clarify this question.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a variable delay.

SetInterval's lack of precision is still fine to use to update what the user sees.

What's not cool is that the rounding effect means I can sit down and rapidly click start and stop over and over for hours and never see this thing tick off a second.

What you need to do is timestamp the clicks, do the math to find the real duration (of time spent while started), calculate what should be display'd, and set a one time (per start click) variable delay before SetInterval's one second ticking starts again.

Do that and no amount of clicking will slow your clock down.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a StopWatch. I just made it. If you know how to read code, which you sort of have to to be on this site, it should be easy to understand.

```js
//<![CDATA[
/* external.js */
var doc, bod, htm, M, I, S, Q, StopWatch, old = onload; // for use on other loads
onload = function(){ // load wrapper - not indented to save space
if(old)old(); // change old var name above and here if using technique on other pages
doc = document; bod = doc.body; htm = doc.documentElement;
M = function(tag){
  return doc.createElement(tag);
}
I = function(id){
  return doc.getElementById(id);
}
S = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelector(selector);
}
Q = function(selector, within){
  var w = within || doc;
  return w.querySelectorAll(selector);
}
StopWatch = function(outputDiv, decimals, interval){
  var dm = typeof decimals === 'number' ? decimals : 3;
  var iv = typeof interval === 'number' ? interval : 10;
  this.zero = '00:00:0'+(0).toFixed(dm); outputDiv.innerHTML = this.zero;
  var st, si, et;
  this.start = function(){
    if(st === undefined){
      st = Date.now();
    }
    else if(et !== undefined){
      st = Date.now()-et+st; et = undefined;
    }
    si = setInterval(function(){
      var t = Date.now()-st, h = Math.floor(t/3600000), hf = h*3600000, m = Math.floor((t-hf)/60000), mf = m*60000, s = Math.floor((t-hf-mf)/1000), sf = s*1000;
      s = (s+(t-hf-mf-sf)/1000).toFixed(dm);
      if(h.toString().match(/^\d$/))h = '0'+h;
      if(m.toString().match(/^\d$/))m = '0'+m;
      if(s.toString().match(/^\d(\.?\d*)?$/))s = '0'+s;
      var out = h+':'+m+':'+s;
      outputDiv.innerHTML = out;
    }, iv);
    return this;
  }
  this.stop = function(){
    if(si){
      if(et === undefined)et = Date.now();
      clearInterval(si); si = undefined;
    }
    return this;
  }
  this.clear = function(){
    this.stop(); st = et = undefined; outputDiv.innerHTML = this.zero;
    return this;
  }
}
I('f').onsubmit = function(){
  return false;
}
var act = I('act'), clear = I('clear'), out = I('out');
var stopWatch = new StopWatch(out);
act.onclick = function(){
  if(this.value === 'start'){
    stopWatch.start(); this.value = 'stop';
  }
  else{
    stopWatch.stop(); this.value = 'start';
  }
}
clear.onclick = function(){
  stopWatch.clear(); out.innerHTML = stopWatch.zero; act.value = 'start';
}
} // end load
//]]>
```

```css
/* external.css */
html,body{
  padding:0; margin:0;
}
body{
  background:#000; overflow-y:scroll;
}
.main{
  width:940px; background:#ccc; padding:20px; margin:0 auto;
}
#out{
  display:inline-block; width:85px; background:#fff; padding:5px 10px; cursor:default;
}
#act,#clear{
  width:55px; cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='content-type' content='text/html;charset=utf-8' />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width' />
    <title>StopWatch</title>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='external.css' />
    <script type='text/javascript' src='external.js'></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div class='main'>
    <form id='f' name='f'>
      <div id='out'></div>
      <input id='act' type='button' value='start' />
      <input id='clear' type='button' value='reset' />
    </form>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you could explain the downvote, that would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Instead of using `setTimeout`, use `requestAnimationFrame()`.

When the timer starts, create a new `Date`, and create a new date every animation frame: subtract the two to get the current value of the timer.

Cache your DOM element into a variable, as you have already done.  Something like this:

```
var result_display = document.getElementById("result");
var timer_is_running = false;
var remembered_time = null;
var timer_start_time;

function start_timer() {
  timer_is_running = true;
  timer_start_time = new Date();
  update_timer_value(accumulated_time);
}

function pause_timer() {
  timer_is_running = false;
}

function update_timer_value(acc_time) {
    var elapsed_time = new Date() - timer_start_time;
    if (remembered_time) {
      elapsed_time += remembered_time;
      remembered_time = null;
    }
    var second_value = Math.floor(elapsed_time);
    result_display.innerHTML = second_value;

    if (timer_is_running) {
      requestAnimationFrame(update_timer_value);
    }
    else {
      remembered_time = elapsed_time;
    }
}
```

Comment: This should be enough to get you started: the disadvantage here is that your timer would keep timing until the next render frame, usually about 6-13ms in the future from when they clicked pause--but that is definitely a solvable problem, and hopefully this code example shows you the general idea.